# Sd Card Reader Not Working after first time use

Tags: sd-card

Last week I got an SD Card Reader to enable me to download my photos from my camera as I can't do it direct from my camera anymore. It worked fine the first time. Then I safely ejected it and the problems started. I tried formatting the removable disc F but Windows said it can't complete format and told me to check if it was read only. I tried unlocking the read only on my card but still no luck. Now I'm getting messages telling me to insert removable media. Surely that's what my card is in the card reader. Windows told me to get help on read only files and how to change them. If I've unlocked the read only how do I get it to download photos again? Should I uninstall then reinstall and if so how do I do it? I need this sorting by Wednesday as I'll be taking photos of steam engines to download on to a railway website.

Comment: Does the card work in your camera still? Can you see (or even add/delete) files? We need to rule out whether it's your card or reader at fault.

Comment: If you're in a hurry buy a USB card reader, making sure it handles your SD spec. They are only a couple of pounds in UK. It is handy to keep in your camera case, so that you can upload to other machines or view on TV when you are away from home. NB Always set the write protect switch when connecting to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see any Physical damage on the reader? If so, it's broken, and I doubt the manufacturer will fix it. Just in case though, call the manufacturer of the SD Card reader. They should be able to help you.